# Simple Codeigniter + HMVC working but how can i working with multiple CI instance like admin and front

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc, sammy.js

First of thank you for my help. I am using CI.3.0 ver. I am using simple CI with HMVC but when i am creating seperate CI then it will not work can any one help me.

MY actutal URL
http://localhost/cms/admin.php?c=users&m=data

Like
http://localhost/cms/admin.php/users

**but this is called application/admin/controller/user.php**

But i want to call module wise like call this one

**application/admin/modules/users/controller/user.php**

My Folder structure are below:

```
-application
    --admin
        ---cache
        ---config
        ---controllers
            ---- Users.php
        ---core
        ---helpers
        ---hooks
        ---language
        ---libraries
        ---log
        ---models
        ---modules
            ---- users
                ------controllers
                    --------Users.php
                ------model
                ------Views
        ---third_party
            ----MX
                Base.php
                Ci.php
                Controller.php
                ..
                ..
                Router.php
        ---views
        ---.htaccess
    --common
        ---cache
        ---ci_session
        ---helpers
        ---libraries
    --frontend
        ---cache
        ---config
        ---controllers
        ---core
        ---helpers
        ---hooks
        ---language
        ---libraries
        ---log
        ---models
        ---modules
        ---third_party
        ---views
        ---.htaccess
-resource
-system
-index.php
-admin.php
.htaccess
```

Comment: This is simpler than you think (if I understood your question correctly)... you do NOT need multiple CI instances. If you need different sections to be accesible only to a specific user group, all you need is separate controllers and define on each of them which user groups can access it. The simplest way is to store the user type as part of the session data and then set a "check" in each controller's construct

Comment: no actually i want to follow this srtrture and in future may be comes 50+ instances in same way. so how can i call hmvc in controller in modules folder.